# Masonry leaving empty gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, masonry

I am having a problem with Masonry and struggling to understand why it's happening.

Basically, I have a 4 column grid of items.
When the 3rd item is bigger than the rest (3x bigger = 75% width of container), masonry is unable to fill that gap.

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb7/2814/

```
congole.log('Please check jsFiddle');
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: SOLUTION: Use Packery instead. http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb7/2816/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to use Packery!
http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb7/2816/

```
$('#container').packery({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: '.sizer'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

<del>The divs are arranged in the same order. To fill the gap you require 4 divs before your "bigger-div" (excluding the one with class "sizer").</del>

```
<div class="item">19</div><!-- Just Added this -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7avyr2u/

EDIT: My reasoning was wrong. But the solution works...

You first div is not in the result... I don't know if this is intentional.
You don't need `sizer` class if the only reason for it is to pass to Masonry.

changing the class of first `div` from `sizer` to `item` and changing the following code will also solve the problem

```
// Init Masonry
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: '.item'
});
```

**Potential Reason:** This might be a bug in their script. I tried different variation of column-width:total-width ratio. It seems to only fill the gaps on previous row, for columns that are not used-up in the current row.

This will give you a better idea:
http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb7/2815/

So to get the layout right. You need to have `X` number of divs before your bigger cell, where `X*columnwidth = width-of-bigger-cell`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what you are saying is not right. Changing the sizer class to item, means the opened div is now the 4th and not 3rd, thats why it works.

Comment: The problem is that the item in the 3rd column never opens properly. .grid-sizer is used by masonry to set columnWidth as %. By renaming .grid-sizer to .item, the previously 3rd item, now becomes the 2nd - which always worked fine.